# Use overwritten value in parent constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, inheritance

I'm invoking a function in constructor where I want to use the variable from child in the function call that's made through parent constructor. For demo purpose I've created a small script to show what I want to do:

```js
 class A{
    intVal = 1;
    constructor() {
     this.identifyClass();   
    }
    identifyClass()
    {
        console.log("I am class A", this.intVal); // This should be the value that B has overwitten
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    intVal = 2;
}

const x = new B();
```

So I'd want that the function in parent constructor should use the value that was overwritten by B ie. `intVal = 2` but currently it uses the original value. Can I use any workaround for this so that I don't have to create a constructor in B and then invoke the function there?

**Note**: It's a very complex app where I don't want breaking changes to A which is being used at a lot of places and the Class B is being exposed to public so I don't want the people using Class B to change anything if possible where currently they just overwrite the instance variable

Comment: If you don't want them to change anything in `A`, `B` and the variable is a private member, you can't make it work. This is the exact reason the OOP encapsulation concept is there so that no one can tamper with it. If you post the actual scenario that you are trying to acheive, may be there will be other solutions. If the variable is a public member, why not just modify it after you create `B` with `x = B();` then `x.intVal=something`?.

Comment: I think I can implement what Dave suggested. I updated the description I can modify A but don't want to introduce any breaking change so using getter, setter I think I'll be good to achieve the goal.

Comment: I think you're right @brainlesscoder I tried but I doubt it's achievable without changing the way B is being used. Since B is being used at a lot of places and possible could break our apps I'd avoid changing it.

Comment: sounds like you are adding new functionality into B and an existing codebase. If you have enough time, I would suggest just add unittests with edge cases around the code, then refactor it. Will save you a lot in long term.

Comment: Yes right I already have unit tests for the common shared package where I was planning to introduce the change required above but I think it's currently not possible without changing the usage of B so would check with team if we can avoid or introduce the changes.

Comment: Does it meet your needs to have A take `intVal` as a constructor parameter? Then `B` would have a no-arg constructor that calls `super(2)`, and the other consumers of A wouldn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it.  We create a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), if the last argument passed to the constructor is not the symbol, then we create a new object, using `this.constructor`, passing in the original arguments, plus the symbol, and *then* call `identify`.  This effectively separates the call to `identify` from the constructor, allowing us to get `this.intVal` from the subclass, while still being transparent to the user of the subclass.

```js
const _sym = Symbol();

class A {
     intVal = 1;
     constructor() {
         const args = Array.from(arguments);
         const _ = args[args.length - 1];
         if (_ !== _sym) {
             args.push(_sym);
             const el = new this.constructor(...args);
             el.identify();
             return el;
         }
     }
     
     identify() {
         console.log(this.intVal);
     }
}

class B extends A {
    intVal = 2;
}


const x = new A();
const y = new B();
```

Comment: Tried but I think for both the above suggestions I need to change the way B is being used in 1st case I'll have to use static variable instead, in the second use getter, setters. I want to avoid changing B currently.